# Merge 2 array and into a third new one when a value is same

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I Have one array called job counts which is as follows **$job**=>

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array([count] => 3[yearmonth] => 2019-7)
        
            [1] => Array([count] => 3[yearmonth] => 2019-9)
        
            [2] => Array([count] => 5[yearmonth] => 2019-10))           
    )
```

And second date array as **$date**=>

```
Array
    ([0] => Array([yearmonth] => 2019-6)
    
     [1] => Array([yearmonth] => 2019-7)
    
     [2] => Array([yearmonth] => 2019-8)
    
     [3] => Array([yearmonth] => 2019-9)
    
     [4] => Array([yearmonth] => 2019-10)
)
```

The job array is not a continuous array. So here I want is if an entry is available in $date but not present in $job then create 3rd array with count = 0 and yearmonth value.
Something like below

```
Array
    ([0] => Array([count] => 0[yearmonth] => 2019-6)
    
     [1] => Array([count] => 3[yearmonth] => 2019-7)
    
     [2] => Array([count] => 0[yearmonth] => 2019-8)
    
     [3] => Array([count] => 3[yearmonth] => 2019-9)
    
     [4] => Array([count] => 5[yearmonth] => 2019-10)
)
```

Comment: Just loop `$date` and check if each `yearmonth` is in `$job` and get the `count` or `0` if not and add to new array.

Comment: Please always post your array data as either `var_export()` or a json_encoded string.

Comment: Your question is a "requirements dump". We always expect you to exhaustively research and try something before posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never underestimate the power of being able to use keys in a very flexible way/manner in php arrays.

```
<?php
//Copied from mickmackusa
$jobs = [
    ['count' => 3, 'yearmonth' => '2019-7'],
    ['count' => 3, 'yearmonth' => '2019-9'],
    ['count' => 5, 'yearmonth' => '2019-10'],         
];
$dates = [
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-6'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-7'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-8'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-9'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-10'],
];
//End copy

/*
    Make the keys of $jobs be the same as values
    of yearmonth: (This makes it easy to compare later on)

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 3
                [yearmonth] => 2019-7
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 3
                [yearmonth] => 2019-9
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 5
                [yearmonth] => 2019-10
            )

        [2019-7] => Array
            (
                [count] => 3
                [yearmonth] => 2019-7
            )

        [2019-9] => Array
            (
                [count] => 3
                [yearmonth] => 2019-9
            )

        [2019-10] => Array
            (
                [count] => 5
                [yearmonth] => 2019-10
            )

    )

*/
foreach($jobs as $key=>$item) {
    $jobs[$item['yearmonth']] = $item;
}

//Create a third array $third_arr based on your $jobs and $dates array
$third_arr = [];
foreach($dates as $item) {
    $key_value = $item['yearmonth'];
    if (isset($jobs[$key_value]['yearmonth'])) {
        //Available in dates and present in $jobs
        //Just copy values from the $jobs item which relates to this yearmonth
        $third_arr[] = $jobs[$key_value];
    }
    else {
        //Available in dates but not present in $job
        $third_arr[] = ['count'=>0, 'yearmonth'=>$key_value];
    }
}
```

Output of third array `$third_arr`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [yearmonth] => 2019-6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
            [yearmonth] => 2019-7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [yearmonth] => 2019-8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
            [yearmonth] => 2019-9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [count] => 5
            [yearmonth] => 2019-10
        )

)
```

A more compressed version of code above would look like:

```
foreach($jobs as $key=>$item) {
    $jobs[$item['yearmonth']] = $item;
}
$third_arr = [];
foreach($dates as $item) {
    $kvalue = $item['yearmonth'];
    isset($jobs[$kvalue]['yearmonth']) ? 
    $third_arr[] = $jobs[$kvalue] : $third_arr[] = ['count'=>0, 'yearmonth'=>$kvalue];
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa - I hope it's ok I stole some code from you ;-)

Comment: I'm not offended but it is my answer with syntax adjusted to be more verbose.  I don't recommend that style of ternary assignment -- again, it is too verbose.  I don't know that this answer adds much value to the page for researchers.

Comment: Just remember that Stack Exchange is a place to educate and empower people while building an ever-maturing repository of knowledge.  This is not a site built to give people magic points.  The points are just "noise" compared to the aforementioned "signal". When you are considering posting, ask yourself if you have something new,  unique, and valuable to share with researchers.  If not, don't post it.  In the same vein, never recommend a solution that you know is "worse" than another answer -- even if it "works".

Comment: Oh I wouldn't say it's your answer. I'm using two foreach-loops setting keys and you are putting values into antoher lookup array with counts. I am also creating a new array becausue OP asked for that and you are modifying the current array. It's another way to solve the same issue yes, but again I don't agree with you that it's your answer. You also have the keys in the incorrect order (I don't think that matters) but it's just a fact.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about the FGITW post, but I am not trying to insult you in an way. If I did - I apologize.

Comment: In your first loop, you are creating a lookup array with yearmonth keys, just like I did.  The differences being that you declare `$key` for no reason and you leave the full subarrays in tact.  I could have created the same array with `array_column($jobs, null, 'yearmonth');` but I know I don't need the surplus data. Then in the second loop you check the lookup array as you iterate -- just as my answer demonstrated.  Except I don't call `isset()` and I don't declare and build a new output array.  It is the same answer written differently.  Now I am a little disappointed so be explaining this.

Comment: I am not saying that you are a FGITW poster, the other user was.

Comment: I actually upvoted your answer. Now I'm starting to regret that ;-) Seriously -we don't agree and that's the way it is sometimes. Yes there are similarities but the programs do not even output identical data and in my mind I am answering what OP are expecting. I'm not saying you are doing it wrong, but I'm saying that's not what OP are stating that he/she wants. I don't mind if you get an an accepted answer but I believe it's up to OP to decide which answer that should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

To efficiently search the `$jobs` array for dates as you iterate the `$dates` array, create a "lookup" array.

The lookup should have keys that represent the relational data (`yearmonth`).

Using each encountered date from the `$dates` array, check if the `yearmonth` value is represented as a key in the lookup -- if so, use the `count` value, if not, set 0.

`&` before a variable means "modify by reference -- so that the original array is mutated instead of needing to declare a new output array.

`??` is the "null coalescing operator", this allows a fallback value to be used if the variable is `null`/undeclared.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ct9Yl))

```
$jobs = [
    ['count' => 3, 'yearmonth' => '2019-7'],
    ['count' => 3, 'yearmonth' => '2019-9'],
    ['count' => 5, 'yearmonth' => '2019-10'],         
];
$dates = [
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-6'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-7'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-8'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-9'],
    ['yearmonth' => '2019-10'],
];

$lookup = array_column($jobs, 'count', 'yearmonth');

foreach ($dates as &$date) {
    $date['count'] = $lookup[$date['yearmonth']] ?? 0;
}

var_export($dates);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'yearmonth' => '2019-6',
    'count' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'yearmonth' => '2019-7',
    'count' => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'yearmonth' => '2019-8',
    'count' => 0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'yearmonth' => '2019-9',
    'count' => 3,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'yearmonth' => '2019-10',
    'count' => 5,
  ),
)
```

---

Alternatively, if you demand that a new output array be declared and the associative subarrays must be in the same order as in your question, then this is my adjustment of the same technique:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cHoIZ))

```
$lookup = array_column($jobs, null, 'yearmonth');

$result = [];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $result[] = $lookup[$date['yearmonth']] ?? ['count' => 0] + $date;
}

var_export($result);
```

The lookup array now contains the full subarray data.  `array_column()` uses `null` as the second parameter to prevent isolating a single row and `yearmonth` as the third parameter to assign the first level keys.

The foreach loop no longer "modifies by reference".  The null coalescing operator is still used to avoid the call of `isset()` and is ideal to concisely write the fallback data.  I am using the "union operator" between the hardcoded array containing the `count` element and the `$date` array -- the avoids the call of `array_merge()` or manually writing the `['yearmonth' => $date['yearmonth']`.  This is a suitable merging technique because the keys are are unique and associative respective to each subarray.

Answer (score 1):

So if you add `count => 0` to the `$date` arrays and index on the `yearmonth` you can index `$job` on `yearmonth` and merge it into `$date`:

```
$result = array_merge(array_column(array_map(function($v) { $v['count'] = 0; return $v; },
                                   $date), null, 'yearmonth'),
                      array_column($job, null, 'yearmonth'));
```

Comment: While this is working, functional-style solution, it will be making 4 array iterations: (`array_map()`, `array_column()`, `array_column()`, then `array_merge()`.  This is more expensive than the solution that I have offered (which only makes 2 iterations over array data).  This isn't an attack, just information to explain the difference to the OP and researchers.

Comment: Yep, just for fun.